# How does master node start all the process in a hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, hadoop2, resourcemanager, namenode

I have set up a Hadoop cluster of 5 virtual machines , using plain vanilla Hadoop. The cluster details are below:

192.168.1.100 - Configured to Run NameNode and SNN daemons
192.168.1.101 - Configured to Run ResourceManager daemon.
192.168.1.102 - Configured to Run DataNode and NodeManager daemons.
192.168.1.103 - Configured to Run DataNode and NodeManager daemons.
192.168.1.104 - Configured to Run DataNode and NodeManager daemons.

I have kept masters and slaves files in each virtual servers.

## masters:

192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101

## slaves file:

192.168.1.102
192.168.1.103
192.168.1.104

Now when I run `start-all.sh` command from `NameNode` machine, how is it able to start all the daemons? I am not able to understand it? There are no adapters installed (or I am not aware of), there are simple hadoop jars present in all the machines so how is `NameNode` machine able to start all the daemons in all the machines (virtual servers).

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namenode connects to the slaves via SSH and runs the slave services.
That is why you need public ssh-keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the slaves, to have their private counterparts be present for the user running the Hadoop namenode.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info; so the Namenode connects to slaves via ssh and executes the commands to run the slave processes. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @CuriousMind yes exactly, that's how it works. That's why you put certain options via ENV variables in the hadoop_env.sh (that file is sourced on the slaves).